How to revalidate current path in Next.js14?
I am rewriting code of a goal tracker app and moving from onSubmit to Server Actions
So basically user can add goals and groups of goals (Relationship, Financial, etc)
It's a simple one page app
Anyways, I want that when a user successfully adds a group (category), the data is immediately reflected in the UI without the need to refresh the page
I tried revalidatePath("/"); and redirect("/"); but to no avail
AddNewGroup component (Client Component since it's nested in a client component "Goals.tsx")
import { createGroup } from "@/server/actions";
import { SubmitButton } from "@/components/Button";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useFormState } from "react-dom";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import { StateResponse } from "@/types";

const AddNewGroup = ({ userId }: { userId: string }) => {
  const [formVisible, setFormVisible] = useState(false);
  const [state, dispatch] = useFormState<StateResponse, FormData>(createGroup, {
    message: "",
    type: "",
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (state.type === "error") {
      toast.error(state.message);
    }
    if (state.type === "success") {
      toast.success(state.message);
    }
  }, [state]);

  return (
    <>
      {formVisible ? (
        <form action={dispatch} className="flex gap-2 mt-2">
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Type here"
            className="input input-bordered w-full max-w-xs"
            name="groupText"
          />
          <input type="hidden" name="userId" value={userId} />
          <SubmitButton />
          <button
            className="btn btn-ghost"
            type="button"
            onClick={() => {
              setFormVisible(false);
            }}
          >
            Cancel
          </button>
        </form>
      ) : (
        <button
          className="btn btn-ou tline"
          type={"button"}
          onClick={() => {
            setFormVisible(true);
          }}
        >
          Add new group
        </button>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default AddNewGroup;


Server Action createGroup
export async function createGroup(
  state: StateResponse,
  formData: FormData,
): Promise<StateResponse> {
  const userId = formData.get("userId") as string;
  const groupText = formData.get("groupText") as string;

  // console.log(userId + " " + groupText);
  if (groupText.trim() === "") {
    return { message: "Missing Field. Failed to Create Group.", type: "error" };
  }
  await dbConnect();
  const session = await mongoose.startSession();
  session.startTransaction();

  try {
    const user = await User.findById(userId).session(session);
    if (!user) {
      return {
        message: "Unauthorized access",
        type: "error",
      };
    }
    // Find the highest order for the user's categories
    const highestOrderCategory = await Category.findOne({ user: userId })
      .sort({ order: -1 })
      .session(session);

    const newOrder = highestOrderCategory ? highestOrderCategory.order + 1 : 1;

    const category = new Category({
      name: groupText,
      user: userId,
      order: newOrder,
      goals: [],
    });

    await category.save({ session });
    await session.commitTransaction();
    return {
      message: `${category.name} was created successfully!`,
      type: "success",
    };
  } catch (error) {
    await session.abortTransaction();
    return {
      message: `Failed to create group! Please try again`,
      type: "error",
    };
  } finally {
    await session.endSession();
  }
  revalidatePath("/");
  redirect("/");
}


Here's the full code on github: https://github.com/waelnassaf/nextjs-goal-tracker
